# Deploy AWS Lambda with function URL via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Since a few days, [AWS Lambdas can be exposed as web services directly without an API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/).

This works fine when setting up through the UI console, but I can’t seem to get it done with Cloudformation, because the resource policy is not attached with `AuthType: NONE`. And without the policy, I get `"message": "Forbidden"` from AWS when trying to access the Lambda through the function url.

My Lambda is the following:

```js
exports.handler = async event => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify("Hello World")
    }
}
```

and here’s the CFN template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  stackName:
    Type: String
  lambdaFile:
    Type: String
  lambdaBucket:
    Type: String

Resources:
  lambdaRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                Effect: "Allow"
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${stackName}:*"
          PolicyName: "lambda"

  runtimeLambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref lambdaBucket
        S3Key: !Ref lambdaFile
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NODE_ENV: production
      FunctionName: !Sub "${stackName}-runtime"
      Handler: runtime.handler
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: !GetAtt lambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: "nodejs14.x"
      Timeout: 5

  lambdaLogGroup:
    Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub "/aws/${stackName}"
      RetentionInDays: 30

  runtimeLambdaUrl:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Url"
    Properties:
      AuthType: NONE
      TargetFunctionArn: !Ref runtimeLambdaFunction

Outputs:
  runtimeLambdaUrl:
    Value: !GetAtt runtimeLambdaUrl.FunctionUrl
```

The interesting thing is that I can add the policy through the UI console, and then it works.

Here’s the initial config screen for the function URL right after CFN deployment:

[image]

This is what I see when pushing the “Edit” button:

[image]

After clicking “Save”, I get the following (note the blue box):

[image]

Also, when I go into “Edit” mode again, I now see the following:

[image]

After that, the function can be accessed via its URL.

I tried to add the policy into my CFN stack, either standalone as `AWS::IAM::Policy`, but then it is not a resource-based policy or as an additional action on the `lambdaRole`. But in either case, I can’t add a `Principal` and the policy doesn’t have an effect.

Does anybody know how I can make a pure Clouformation deployment for a Lambda with a function URL? Or is this a bug in Cloudformation and/or Lambda?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? any chance you could share the final template?

Comment: The solution posted by Marcin below is the correct one. Sorry, I can’t share the template as it has much more details and I would have to massively clean it up first.

Comment: yep tried that and did not worked neither, might be some other problem. Thanks anyway, Gonna stick to Api Gateway anyway, too much hassle configuring this 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your template is missing [AWS::Lambda::Permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html), thus its does not work. You already know what the permissions should be based on AWS console inspection, so you have to recreate those permissions using `AWS::Lambda::Permission`. This allows you to specify [FunctionUrlAuthType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html#cfn-lambda-permission-functionurlauthtype).

Comment: I’ll be damned, that was it. The interesting thing is, I’ve transformed it from a stack using API Gateway, and I didn’t need a Permission resource there. (And I could swear I had looked at AWS::Lambda::Permission yesterday, but didn’t find anything related to FunctionUrl.) Anyway, thanks!